# finding peak values and corresponding timestamps

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to use scipy to identify peaks of my signals and try to get the corresponding timestamps of those peaks. Used `scipy.signal.find_peaks` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)

I have a large data file with `data` (Numpy ndarray) that contains all the signal values with sampling rate 200, and `times` with all the corresponding sample numbers of each signal.

To have a snippet of the data,

```py
# len(data[0]) is 1028721
data[0] = array([0.00333048, 0.00333095, 0.00333494, ..., 0.0062428 , 0.00624095,
       0.00624318])

# len(times) is 1028721
times = array([0.000000e+00, 5.000000e-03, 1.000000e-02, ..., 5.143590e+03,
       5.143595e+03, 5.143600e+03])
```

so far I got to get the peak points (mostly from scipy examples) using:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, peak_prominences
peaks, properties = find_peaks(data[0], height=None, distance = 200)

plt.plot(data[0])
plt.plot(peaks, data[0][peaks], "x")
```

If I plot the above, I do get a bunch of 'x' marks on the peak points, which is great so far.
However, when I try to get the values of each peak, if I do `peaks` or `properties`, `peaks` returns an index which I do not know how it was derived, and properties is just an empty dictionary.

I was wondering if I could get some help on actually getting each peak's signal values. I know it's only a snippet of my codes shown above, but was wondering if I could get on help on utilizing the `find_peaks` better.

Ideally, I was thinking getting like `peaks[0]` or `properties['height']` returning me the signal values.

Then, I was wondering how I could map on these peak points to the original `times` ndarray to get the corresponding timestamps.

Any pointers would be really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally before you use find_peaks you broke the signal into time (time_np) and signal (amp_np) arrays. This is easily done with wavfile.read(wav_file_path) with returns fs_rate and signal.

Scipy.signal's find_peaks should return the amplitudes of the peaks that find_peaks finds.

For each amp in the returned peaks array you can find the index in the np_array where the value at that index is this max amp. This index should give you the index at which to find the time stamp of the peak.

Note, you may need to threshold the peaks returned to return only the tallest peaks. If this cuts off too many peaks you can iterate through and ignore peaks that are x distance close to the previous peak (don't label one hill as multiple peaks).

Answer (score 0):

An example of what I would do is like below

time = np.array(rawdat.time_s[100000:5000000])
current = np.array(rawdat.current_nA[100000:5000000])*-1 ## needed as find_peaks only finds peaks and the data is looking at minimums so data is inverted by *-1

I would use the
peaks, properties = find_peaks(current, prominence=(0.2), width=5, rel_height=0.5). ##This selects only peaks that 0.2 or larger in terms of amplitude.

results_half = peak_widths(x, peaks, rel_height=0.5) is then used to get the peak widths of peaks at the respected heights such as Full Width Half Maximum (FWHM). This was being used to determine the peak asymmetry (AS) of the peaks at various heights. This was done by AS = (PF-P50)/(P50-PS) where PF is time of peak finish (at the % peak of interest such as FWHM =50%), PS is corresponding time of peak start and P50 is the time of the max of peak.